# Eclipse SVN Keep Asking "Provide Authentication Information"

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse CDT, I imported a project checked out from svn. Then I wanted to sync with repo (or "show annotation" or whatever needs to sync with svn), I was prompted this window:

[image]

After I clicked 'OK', it showed up again, and again, never ends... Until I gave up and click "Cancel". What is the reason and how can i get rid of it?

Answer (score 3):

I hate to say so, but this is stupid...I just needed to drag and make the dialog window bigger, like this:

[image]

Comment: Faced a similar issue and it was so annoying!! thanks